# Azure logic apps Deployment in Different Environment

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I am using azure Standard service plan and developing Logic Apps Work flows. Now i want to deploy it to different environment like QA/UAT.

I have referred few MSDN blogs and found out We can do the logic apps deployment to different subscriptions via Visual studio with Azure SDK. However I am using API Apps in the logic apps work flows like SQL connector, Transformation service, BizTalk Xpath Extractor etc..

Can you please let me know how do we deploy API Apps to different Environment. Please suggest.

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create the logic app with the connectors you want and then export that ARM template LogicApp -> Settings -> Export Template. Of course this template might not be the ideal approach since it will have lot of stuff hard coded specific to that LA.

The good approach will be to create a new Azure resource Group project which has

- the logic app ARM template,
- just copy the defn part from you existing logic apps int the template definition section
- make sure you have the connection resources creation added as part of you template.

Some useful resources
1. Checkout this MSDN [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-create-deploy-template/).
2. There is a utility also to get the LA templates, [read this](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Hi Tushar, I am unable to find out the LogicApp -> Settings -> Export Template. I am going through the URLs for creating ARM Template. but  I have few clarifications like when we create a SQL connector with on-premise setup. there is some websites hosted on Local IIS Server. so how do we configure those in deployment scripts.

Comment: For local IIS server websites you can use powershell scripts to do that. Some pointers http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/powershell-scripts-for-automating-web-deploy-setup